# VS Code Prettier FormatOnSave stopped working in my new project

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app, prettier

I created a new project with create-react-app. I have configured prettier tool. Unfortunately, formatting on save doesn't work on this project. Works fine on other projects. What could have happened?

My VSCode setting is:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a new project, I presume that means it is not in source control. The setting "modifications" will not work in that situation, as described on the site (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
// Controls if format on save formats the whole file or only modifications. Only applies when `editor.formatOnSave` is enabled.
//  - file: Format the whole file.
//  - modifications: Format modifications (requires source control).
//  - modificationsIfAvailable: Will attempt to format modifications only (requires source control). If source control can't be used, then the whole file will be formatted.
```

Try using "modificationsIfAvailable" instead:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable",
}
```